# Generic Repository Structuremap IOC question

Tags: structuremap, ioc-container

I'm new to IOC and strcturemap but i want to know how I can register different classes that implements from the same interface like IRepository that implements CustomerRepository and CategoryRepository for example.
And, as you can see, if i can use this with generic types.
Like Repository or Repository

```
x.ForRequestedType<IRepository<Category>>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<IRepository<Category>>();
```

tried this bit It didn't worked..any help whould be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know how StructureMap exactly works, but I would propably write `Is.OfConcreteType<Repository<Category>>'. `Repository`, `Repository`, `Repository`, not `IRepository`.

Answer (score 2):

When configuring StructureMap, you can use the Scan API to auto-register the closed types.

```
Scan(x =>
{
  x.TheCallingAssembly();
  x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>));
});
```

This feature is in the latest trunk, but I'm not sure if it is any released version, and probably not yet in the official documentation. However, there is a good [blog post that explains it](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/12/17/advanced-structuremap-connecting-implementations-to-open-generic-types.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily MVCPoco.Data.IRepository`1[[MVCPoco.Core.Category, MVCPoco.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], MVCPoco.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

got the latest version... the project runs but when i inject in the constructor a IRepository it gives me that error.

Comment: I need to register ir? the name of the repository is Repository.cs... I counn't figure out what i'm doing wrong!

Comment: I ran into the same problem, make sure the class it can't find is public.